# "Take photo" option is not displaying using CNContactViewController while setting contact image in iOS 12

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xamarin.ios, ios12

We have a feature in our application to save user entered phone number to iOS native contacts.

For that purpose we are using CNContactViewController.

```
var editor = CNContactViewController.FromNewContact(contact);
editor.Delegate = new MyCNConatactViewControllerDelegate(DismissCallBack);
editor.AllowsActions = true;
editor.AllowsEditing = true;
```

But "Take photo" option is not displaying while setting the contact image using CNContactViewController in iOS 12, but i can able to see "Take photo" in iOS Version 13,14.

In iOS 12, I can see only one "Choose from gallery" option.

Could you help me to show "Take photo" option button in iOS 12 as well?

Note:- We tried by adding photo permission in info.plist as well. That didn't help.

Comment: Did you run it on the real device or simulator ?

Comment: Not simulator. Tested using real device.

Comment: It may still be an issue with the iOS version, you could go to Apple's official forums to report.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I have asked in the apple developer forum. No response received.